# What does it mean if my system shuts down unexpectedly with no message in the logs?

Tags: shutdown, hardware

My system occasionally powers off by itself, leaving no messages in `kern.log` or `syslog`. Does this mean the hardware is faulty?

**Update**

This just happened again, while I was sitting in front of the computer. The system froze for about 10 seconds before powering off. There is nothing relevant in `syslog`. The crash occurred shortly after the normal exit from `anacron`:

```
Jun 29 12:00:17 james-MS-7B05 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jun 29 12:00:17 james-MS-7B05 anacron[19522]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-06-29
Jun 29 12:00:17 james-MS-7B05 anacron[19522]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jun 29 12:03:25 james-MS-7B05 systemd-modules-load[551]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jun 29 12:03:25 james-MS-7B05 systemd-modules-load[551]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jun 29 12:03:25 james-MS-7B05 systemd-modules-load[551]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jun 29 12:03:25 james-MS-7B05 systemd-modules-load[551]: Inserted module 'coretemp'
Jun 29 12:03:25 james-MS-7B05 lvm[557]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" monitored
Jun 29 12:03:25 james-MS-7B05 systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
...
```

I think overheating can be eliminated since `psensor` shows the temps are all normal. As mentioned by @user535733, the power supply is a likely culprit, but I wonder if a driver such as the `Nvidia` module could cause a system freeze?

**Update2**

This time it powered off under heavy load, with a string of NULL characters in `syslog`:

```
Jul  3 15:17:01 james-MS-7B05 CRON[20203]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Anyone know what this means? Could the string of nulls happen with a power supply failure?

Comment: Is it shutting down or powering off without warning?  Mine was doing the power off without warning and it turned out it was my power supply was bad.  That is given that there is no overheating which can also cause instant power off as a safety feature.

Comment: It is powering off, with no shut down sequence. I edited the question to be more clear.

If there was overheating, wouldn't there be warning messages in `kern.log`?

Comment: I believe that it would possibly write that out, but my motherboard does not have all the sensors that Ubuntu can read, so I have to rely on what I can get from the BIOS of the system.  I run an older legacy board.  So, unfortunately on mine I would only be able to possibly tell by the temp inside the case.

Comment: Are there any `core` dumps on the system? Generally: hardware failure that is not directly related to a power failure always has an error notice in /var/log/syslog and even a power failure often has the system dumping a last effort error notice into /var/log/syslog. So start there: check syslog and include some lines before the crash into the question. Maybe there is a lead there (a lead could also be a line without an "error").

Comment: @Rinzwind no core dumps. I have included the lines from `syslog` as you suggested.

Comment: Did you check how well the cables are connected?

Comment: The power cables? They are fine, and if that was the problem I think it would power off immediately instead of freezing for 10 seconds first?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct - powering off without warning or logs is a classic symptom of faulty hardware.

Ubuntu does NOT have a "poweroff without warning" or "poweroff with logging the reason" feature (who would want those?).

Unexpected poweroff may have many possible causes. The two most common are overheating and a failing power supply. Look to those first.